# How to launch new tasks on ecs instances which come up in autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I have an ECS Cluster which has two instances as defined in an autoscaling group with 2 as minimum capacity,

I have defined the ecs service to run two containers per instance when it is created or updated. So it launches two containers per ecs instances in the ecs cluster.

Now, suppose when I stop/terminate an instance in that cluster a new instance will automatically come up since the autoscaling group has a minimum capacity of two.

**The problem is when the new instance come up in the autoscaling group it does not run two tasks which are defined to be in service, instead, it runs 4 tasks on one ecs instance and the other new ecs instance doesn't have any task running on it.**

**How could I manage that whenever a new instance come up in Auto Scaling group it also has those two tasks running?**

Answer (score 1):

if you want those two ec2 instance to be dedicated for those 4 tasks then you can modify task definition memory limits and make it require half of your 1 ecs instance memory.

Let's say you have t3.small then your task definitions limits would be 1gb for memory limit. in this way if you have one t3.small instance you will get only 2 tasks running on it. whenever you add another t3.small instance you should fulfil the missing required memory and another two tasks will run on that new t3.small instance.

You can also consider running 1 task per ecs instance, to do so in service creation choose to have Deamon service type. and give more memory to your task in task definition. so every new ec2 instance will have 1 running task for this service all the time.